# Why is a vector treated as if it was passed by value even when it is passed by const reference?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, vector, reference

I was recently coding a very simple `class`, which is responsible for finding the min and max values in a `std::vector` and found out, that even when I pass the collection as a `const reference` to the `class`' constructor and then change the vector (ie. push an element into it or remove one from it) from outside, the vector inside the `class` remains unchanged.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class MinMaxFinder
{
public:
    MinMaxFinder(const std::vector<int>& numbers) : numbers(numbers)
    {
    }
    const int Min() const
    {
        this->findMinAndMax();
        return this->min;
    }
    const int Max() const
    {
        this->findMinAndMax();
        return this->max;
    }

protected:
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    int min;
    int max;

    void findMinAndMax()
    {
        // std::minmax_element call to find min and max values
    }
};
```

I assumed the point of passing a reference is so that a large object is not copied, the way my code works now, however, seems like it does copy the collection.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "MinMaxFinder.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, -6, 12, 158, -326 };
    MinMaxFinder mmf(v);

    v.push_back(-9999999);
    v.push_back(9999999);

    auto min = mmf.Min();
    auto max = mmf.Max();
}
```

The value of `min` will be `-326`, the value of `max` will be `158`, even though it is pretty clear that the value `9999999` is much larger than `158`.

I managed to fix this behaviour by changing the definition of the private member `numbers` to `std::vector<int>& numbers`, but is it the correct solution?

Still, why would the state of internal collection remain unchaged, does it not defy the definition of passing by const ref?

Comment: The *vector* in your class is **not** a reference so it receives a *copy* of the *vector* is passed *by reference* to the constructor.

Comment: @Galik: Please don't write answers in the comments section. There are three good answers below, where they belong.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Its too trivial for an answer, most likely a typo.

Comment: @Galik: Irrelevant. _Answers do not go in the comments section_. If you think the question is too trivial to answer, _don't answer it!!!!!!_ You are willfully violating the Stack Exchange model! Besides, I don't think this is a typo.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then how are we supposed to discover whether or not a question should be closed on the basis of it being "a simple typographical error" without some comments? Do we have to supply an answer every time we suspect a typo?

Comment: @Galik: I addressed that. If you personally believe the question shouldn't be answered, don't answer it. Comments are not for chat — you could say "are you sure this isn't a typo?" as that's a request for clarification. But answering it instead in the comments is wrong. Answers go in the answer section. That's why it's the answer section. Not sure how else to put it; seems fairly self-evident to me *shrug*

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Okay. In future I'll make sure to make it a question .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::vector<int> numbers;` should be `const std::vector<int>& numbers;` this way you reference an object without copy it or having the ability of changing it.

but seriously, what is the point of this class? huge overkill! just use `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` or `std::minmax_element`..

```
auto minimun = std::min_element(numbers.begin(),numbers.end());
```

Comment: I'm guessing the point is to avoid iterating over the vector twice. In which case, use `std::minmax_element`. Which is mentioned in the comment in the question already.

Comment: So if I am passing a reference of type `A` to an object's constructor and assigning the reference to a member which is actually a value of type `A`, it will be copied? Changing the type of `numbers` from value to reference helps, as I have mentioned in the question... I don't program in C++ very much, is it more common to just call s standard algorithm, such as `std::minmax_element` directly, rather than creating a class to wrap it (`std::minmax_element` is the algorithm I am using to find the min and max afterall)?

Comment: you always copy something. in this case - the memory address, not the whole vector, which is ok. the compielr will prevent you from changing what the reference is pointing at by preventing compilation

Answer (score 3):

The member initialisation `numbers(numbers)` called on construction *will* take a deep copy.

If you were to compute the minimum and maximum values on construction, then you wouldn't need to retain `numbers` as a class member.

You *could* store a *reference* as the class member, but then you'd have to be careful to limit the lifetime of your class instance to that where the vector is in scope, else the reference could *dangle*. I'd advise against doing that.

Comment: I didn't want to compute the min and max in the constructor but in the `Min()` and `Max()` methods, directly because I wanted the values to be recalculated if the vector changed from outside scope, but seeing as storing the reference would probably bring more problems than benefits, having plain `std::minmax_element` in my code is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 3):

> I assumed the point of passing a reference is so that a large object is not copied

Yeah, that's right, and the large object isn't copied when "calling" the constructor.

However, your data member is a value, not a reference, so the argument is immediately copied to initialise the member.

It's like writing this:

```
std::vector<int> v;
const std::vector<int>& ref = v;
std::vector<int> v2 = ref;
```

then wondering why `v2` is a copy. :)

Comment: That shed some light on the problem. I don't mainly program in C++ so some terms are confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The member varialbe `numbers` is not declared as reference, so it will be copied when get initialized, even though the ctor's parameter is passed by reference. Try to change the declaration to:

```
protected:
    const std::vector<int>& numbers;
```

Comment: This is kind of dangerous, as you can easily pass a temporary as a const-ref parameter. And end up with a dangling reference.